# Checkout not working after remove Apple Pay

Tags: magento2, braintree

Using Magento 2. Another user integrated Apple Pay on both our Magento and payment gateway Braintree

Realized need Apple Pay account as well and don't have one.  So decided to remove Apple Pay from both Magento and Braintree

But now when trying to go to checkout (after entering shipping info), get to Payment Method page but get the "spinner" and nothing happens...just "spinner" keeps going.

I tried flushing cache but still no luck.  I checked chrome "inspect" and see message "Braintree ApplePay Apple Pay is not supported on this device/browser".  NOt sure if this is the issue

Even though Apple Pay has been disabled in Magento, is it still some how being accessed at checkout and need to remove in another place?

Thanks

Comment: what did you get in your browser network tab?

Comment: All looks good. Calls to paypal are 200s.  Interesting that some apple js are showing up in network.  If Apple Pay was disabled, why are ths js still showing up?

Comment: because it is still installed on your webshop. unless you completely uninstall it, that time only it will be removed as well

Comment: Apple Pay was still enabled but turns out it was possibly due to having Paypal Express enabled.  After disabling PP Express, now can get to checkout.

Comment: @user20719 How you have implemented apple pay in magento2?